# find the integrating factor for the differential equation, $(xy^2+2x^2y^3)dx+(x^2y-x^3y^2)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$(xy^2+2x^2y^3)dx+(x^2y-x^3y^2)dy=0$

$xy(y+2xy^2)dx+xy(x-x^2y)dy=0$

$f(x,y)=xy(y+2xy^2)$

$g(x,y)=xy(x-x^2y)$

Here, xy is a common term for both, f(x,y) and g(x,y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This D.E is of the form
$$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$$where $M(x,y)=xy^2+2x^2y^3$ and $N(x,y)=x^2y-x^3y^2\qquad$
Now $$Mx-Ny=3x^3y^3\neq0$$ and $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$ can be written in the form $$f_1(x,y)ydx+f_2(x,y)xdy=0$$where $f_1(x,y)=xy+2x^2y^2$ and $f_2(x,y)=xy-x^2y^2\qquad\qquad$ $\mbox{Hence the I.F will be} \frac{1}{Mx-Ny}=\frac{1}{3x^3y^3}$